# Identifying the error in my failed proof for "irreducible closed subset of a topological space"

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

> Question: Let Y be an non-empty topological space; prove that it has an irreducible subset.

*My attempt*

Definition: The **Closure** of a set, $cl(\mathcal{Y})$, is the set $\mathcal{Y}$ together with all of its limit points.

*Proof*:

Let $\mathcal{Y} \in Y$ and $y=$ cl$\{\mathcal{Y}\}$.

Consider $y= y_1 \cup y_2$ where $y_1$ and $y_2$ are closed.

Now suppose $\mathcal{Y} \in y_1$, so $\{\mathcal{Y}\} \subseteq y_1$

Thus $y =$ cl$\{\mathcal{Y}\} \subseteq y_1$

Because $y \subseteq y_1$ then clearly $y = y_1$.

Thus by the definition above, y is irreducible. FIN

My answer has been marked as incorrect but without further comments; can anyone point out where I am going wrong?

Comment: If you are supposing that $y$ is a candidate for an irreducible set in $Y$, then you must show that $y$ can't be written as a union of two *proper* subsets of $y$, each of which is *closed in*  $y$. You haven't shown that the $y_i$ are proper subsets of $y$ -- and in fact, you showed that $y_1$ is NOT a proper subset of $y$.

Comment: What is your definition of an irreducible set?

Comment: Using upper-case script letters for points and lower-case plain letters for sets is rather strange, but there’s nothing wrong with the proof. Someone who was being *very* picky could say that you should have said that **without loss of generality** we may suppose that $\mathcal{Y}\in y_1$, but that certainly isn’t enough reason to mark the whole thing wrong. In fact I gave the same proof in answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1993385/does-every-non-empty-topological-space-have-an-irreducible-closed-subset) a few days ago.

Comment: @MPW: The OP *did* show that $y$ cannot be written as the union of two proper closed subsets: he showed that if it’s written as the union of two closed subsets, the one that contains the point $\mathcal{Y}$ is in fact all of $y$.

Comment: @Alexis: A set is irreducible if it is not the union of two relatively closed proper subsets.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott : Hmm, I guess you're right. Guess I got turned around, my bad. I also agree with your assessment of OP's notation BTW. +1. I'll leave my comment there so your response makes sense to other readers. Too bad I can't edit it with strikethrough, editing period has expired.

Comment: @MPW If I understand you correctly, you are suggesting that by assuming that I could write $y$ as a union of two proper subsets $y_1$ and $y_2$ I was "fixing" my contraction, before actually drawing my contradiction?

You are right by saying I showed $y_1$ is not a proper subset of $y$ because I had hoped this was the contradiction I needed to draw. Ofcourse if I had proved that both $y_i$s WERE in fact proper then I would have proved that the closure of a single point set IS reducible (which would be a much more impressive proof given that it false!)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes my notation is horrible, as it was for "fun" as apposed to a real "grade" I was a little hasty in my latex write up (Perhaps my lecturer was so disgusted by my notation he gave up reading the proof?)
To note, I added that we pick $y_1$ WLOG but didnt included that in my OP as it was just spacefilling. 
Thank you both for your feedback, although I must admit I would rather I had made a foolish mistake than for my (apparently correct, by sample size of 2) to be correct but striked as wrong?

Comment: @Max: It’s definitely correct.

Comment: @MaxBoxer : Yes, see my comment to Brian. I was mistaken.

Comment: I concur with Brian M. Scott on the correctness of your work. Your notational style confused me at first but there's nothing illogical with it.